# Should I use new to make an object property in a typescript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's my Typescript class and interface:

```
interface ITest {
    qs: ITestQuestion[];
    message: string;
}

interface ITestQuestion {
    answer: string;
}

class QuestionHomeController {

    test: ITest = {
        qs: null,
        message: string = "xxxxx"
    }
    constructor() {

        this.test.qs = // << setting to An Array of Test Questions
    }
}
```

The code fails because this.test is not defined.

How should I define this and should I create a new test object in my constructor? Also is this the correct way for me to declare the interfaces?

I am a bit confused about how properties work in a Typescript class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to initialize an array just use `[]`:

```
interface ITest {
    qs: ITestQuestion[];
}

interface ITestQuestion {
    answer: string;
}

class QuestionHomeController {

    test: ITest;
    constructor() {

        // initialize test
        this.test =
        {
            qs: [
                { answer: 'first answer' },
                { answer: 'second answer' }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

> should I create a new test object in my constructor?

Your choice.

> Also is this the correct way for me to declare the interfaces?

Yes

**Update**

> If there was something like a property called "ready" in my class then how would I declare that with ready: string = null; before my constructor or should I declare: ready: string; and then in the constructor do ready = null

If I already have the value `message:string = 'default message';` I do it at the variable declaration. If I need to load it from the server I do it in the constructor.

**Update 2**

> what if you have a property like test with one property you know about and the other qs that gets loaded from the server

I would do the following:

```
interface ITestQuestion {
    answer: string;
}

interface ITest {
    local: string;
    server: ITestQuestion[];
}

class QuestionHomeController {

    test: ITest = {
        local: 'something',
        server: []
    };
    constructor() {

        // request from server then: 
        this.test.server = [
            { answer: 'first answer' },
            { answer: 'second answer' }
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: If there was something like a property called "ready" in my class then how would I declare that with ready: string = null; before my constructor or should I declare: ready: string; and then in the constructor do ready = null; ?

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but what if you have an object property like test with one property inside that which you know about and the other qs that gets loaded from the server later? As it's an object I assume I would need to initialize in the constructor. Is that correct ?